# Is this forgivable

Tags: halal-haram, sin, punishment, forgiveness, tawba

If anyone is addicted to a major sin but then he leaves the sin for Allah and he does tawbah and promises never to repeat it again does Allah forgive him? Jazak Allah

Comment: sincere tawbah = 100% chance of Allah forgiving you. doubting Allah's rahma is a big sin.

Comment: Thank you my Brother